# C# ClickOnce deployment for Windows Services?

Tags: c#, windows-services, clickonce

What are some best practices for being able to deploy a Windows service that will have to be updated?

I have a Windows service that I will be deploying but might require some debugging and new versions during the beta process. What is the best way to handle that? Ideally, I'd like to find a ClickOnce-style deployment solution for Windows services but my understanding is that this does not exist. What is the closest I can get to ClickOnce for a Windows service?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002462/how-can-i-write-a-java-application-that-can-update-itself-at-runtime/4002465#4002465

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple solution that I use is to merely stop the service and x-copy the files from my bin folder into the service folder.

A batch file to stop the service then copy the files should be easy to throw together.

```
Net stop myService
xcopy \\myServerWithFiles\*.* c:\WhereverTheServiceFilesAre
net start myService
```

Comment: I like this one, quick and easy!

Comment: Hey I like this. I essentially do the same thing by hand when debugging.

Answer (score 4):

I have a system we use at work here that seems to function pretty well with services. Our deployed system has around 20-30 services at any given time. At work we use a product called TopShelf you can find it here http://topshelf-project.com/

Basically TopShelf handles a lot of the service related stuff. Installing, Uninstalling etc all from the cmd line of the service. One of the very useful features is the ability to run as console for debugging. You build one service, and with a different cmd line start you can run it as a console to see the output of the service. We added one custom feature to this software that lets us configure profiles in advance. Basically our profiles configure a few things like logging, resource locations etc so that we can control all that without having to republish any code. All we do is run a command like

D:\Services\ServiceName.exe Core.Profiles.Debug **or** 
D:\Services\ServiceName.exe Core.Profiles.Production

to get different logging configurations.

Our build script creates install.cmd and uninstall.cmd scripts for each of our services all we do is copy the files to the server and run the script. If we want to see debug output we stop the service and double click the exe and we get a console to read all the output.

One more thing that topshelf has which we don't use because its not necessary is the concept of shelving (there is documentation on this website for this). This allows you to update the service without having to "restart" but you still need to copy the files manually unless you build an automated system for that.

However, my suggestion if you need 100% service availability is to have a redundant system. No matter how you configure your service for updates you cannot avoid hardware failure causing downtime without an automated failover system. If said system was in place my recommended update strategy would be to turn off 1 node, update, test, turn on turn off the other node, update, test and turn the 2nd node back on. You can do this all of course with a simple script. This may be a more complicated system than you need but if you can't take a service offline for a simple restart that takes 5 seconds then you really need some system in place to deal with hardware issues because I can guarantee it will happen eventually.

Answer (score 3):

Since a service is long-running anyway, using ClickOnce style deployment might not be viable - because ClickOnce only updates when you launch the app.  A service will typically only be launched when the machine is rebooted.

If you need automatic update of a service then your best bet might be to hand-code something into the service, but I'd forsee problems with almost any solution: most install processes will require some level of user interaction (if only to get around UAC), so I can't imagine this would lead an answer that doesn't involve getting a logged-on user in front of the screen at some point.

One idea that might just work is active-directory deployment (or some similar equivalent).  If your service is deployed via a standard MSI-type installer, AD allows you to update the application silently as part of the computer policy.  I suspect you'd have to force the server to refresh the AD policy (by rebooting or using `gpupdate` from the console), but other than that it should be a hands-off deployment.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the "plugin" approach on this, that is, using the [`Proxy Design Pattern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).

[image]

While using this pattern, an independant thread may verify over a folder for updates. You will need to use [`ShadowCopy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) over your assembly deployment. When your service update-thread encounters a new version of your service, it shall unload the current production assembly and load the new version, without stopping the service itself. Even more! Your service should never notice the difference, if there is no breaking code within your assembly.

Comment: +1.  Similar to the answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002462/how-can-i-write-a-java-application-that-can-update-itself-at-runtime/4002465#4002465

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create a normal setup project, and add the windows service project output in that setup project.

For more information please refer to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816169.