# How to write code which can get updates?

Tags: java, c#-4.0

If we develop certain software and make exe file. Then I find some bug in it and I fix it. Then how to give updates to users? can I send whole exe file again or I make dll files and send dll files which have bugs in it? What to do in case of Java?

Comment: Do you want to auto update the application?

Comment: Yes. but How to give updates if application has bugs means how to change exe file?

Comment: You need a temporary application that updates the main application and then start the main app again. You could it update partially or complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For .net, You can use [ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
but it has a lot of limitations, e.g. you can not change installation location: application goes to appdata folder etc.

What I currently do is have a autoUpdate.exe

1. main app start, start autoUpdate.exe, main app exit
2. autoUpdate.exe check whether have new versions(by compare main app's
   assembly version or extra version file that only store version like
   2.0.0.1123).
3. If new version found, download and replace main app, pass a no_check argument to main app,start main app.
4. If no new
   versin, also pass a no_check argument to main app,start main app.

Answer (score 0):

For answers to the Java aspect of this question, refer to [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002462/how-can-i-write-a-java-application-that-can-update-itself-at-runtime).

Alternatively, JNLP removes the problem entirely by download the application (and updates) on the user's workstation.  The downloaded artefacts are then cached to reduce start-up times and network costs.