# Create Instance of a Class and Export to File

Tags: java, file, class, instance

How do I make a class instance and then export it to a file? Hope you can help. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Testing {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Testing t = new Testing();

    String fileName = ("C:/Users/Brandon/Desktop/Java/copy.java");

     try {
            FileWriter fileWriter =
                new FileWriter(fileName);

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =
                new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

            bufferedWriter.write(t);

            bufferedWriter.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error writing to file '"
                + fileName + "'");
```

I get this error message:

> The method write(int) in the type BufferedWriter is not applicable for the arguments (Testing).

How do I fix this?

Comment: How about just [serializing](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) it?

Comment: It's saying that a `Testing` object is not an `int`, which is what the parameter wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how your code may be looking for that part:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Testing implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Testing t = new Testing();
    String fileName = new String("copy.ser");
    t.write(t, fileName);
}

public void write(Testing t, String fileName) {

    try {

        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("copy.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        oos.writeObject(t);
        oos.close();
        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error writing to file '"
            + fileName + "'");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but in the file this is what it gives me: ¬í sr Testing         xp What I'm looking to do is create a program that can create itself in another file, I'm starting to think this isn't the way to do it.

Comment: May be this will be helpful then
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002462/how-can-i-write-a-java-application-that-can-update-itself-at-runtime
It is on updating itself, but it can be used to create new file

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *just* write a Java object to a file. The process to do so is called *serialization* and it imposes certain requirements on the object. Look at [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) to get started.

Comment: Even if its another Java file?

Comment: There is __absolutely__ no point in exporting an instance of a Java class to a `.java` (as in Java source code) file - I think you are maybe mis-understanding something here. Please explain further what you're trying to do, maybe we can dis-entangle it then.

Comment: I'm trying to get it to create it self in a different program

Comment: can I write it using    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp");
       ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

       oos.writeInt(12345);
       oos.writeObject(t));
       

       oos.close();