# Auto Update for javafx (Desktop application) application?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, inno-setup, install4j, launch4j

I'm little new in javafx8 . I had created a System based application in java which is working fine but for new functionality i have to re-install it again & again .

please suggest me the best way for auto update of my application .

I try updateFX but it doesn't work .
I'm creating setup using launch4j and inno-setup .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002462/how-can-i-write-a-java-application-that-can-update-itself-at-runtime

Comment: You have added the the install4j tag to your question. Have you tried install4j? It has auto-update functionality.

Comment: Yes .  I tried it but it's not completely open source .  I want it be done by Java or open source technology .