# Automated updates for Java applications

Tags: java, auto-update

What is the best practice for creating an automated update system for an Java application? Are there some special tips to keep in mind? Or do I just download a new .jar file and replace the old one?

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002462/how-can-i-write-a-java-application-that-can-update-itself-at-runtime

Comment: Oh thank you. That helped a lot

Comment: @REHANSHIKKALGAR - You should flag as a duplicate.

Comment: thank u.. i will do it now