# Update of .Jar converted to .exe ( or .dmg/ .deb )

Tags: java, applet, executable-jar, launch4j, java-11

I've recently migrated an applet to a standalone application which uses Java Swing after the disappearance of applets in Java 11.

Then, I converted my application.jar to an executable file (Windows/Mac/Linux).

The problem is that I'd like to keep updating my app versions with bug fixes in a flexible way. My goal is to maintain versions with batch or other means but without re-installing the entire application.

I wonder if someone already have worked on this type of technology?

Comment: *"I wonder if someone already have worked on this type of technology?"* Yes. It's called Java Web Start and is based on the same plug-in that runs applets (and has been deprecated).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002462/how-can-i-write-a-java-application-that-can-update-itself-at-runtime

Comment: Thank you , https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyhXQ.jpg