# Self upgrading Java application running on Windows

Tags: java, windows, upgrade

I have a Java application running on Windows (via Windows service using a batch file).

I am trying to find a way to auto-upgrade the Java app when new release is available (accessible through a REST service).

Since the Java app is running, its jar file cannot be replaced.

Suggestion on how the self upgrade can be done is welcome.

Comment: Use separate "updator" aplication for that.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4002462/2158271) and [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4002730/2158271).